# I am using firebase_admob to implement ads in my flutter app, but ads are not working in release build apk

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, admob

The test ads show with no problem, and even the real ads were appearing on my app when i made an debug build, when i realized the debug build is working fine and made a final release, the ads stopped appearing on my app. Even now on my emulator the app shows the test ads, but with the released app, no ads appear. 
I haven't received any communication either as to why this is happening. Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

i have already tried to install released app on real device but no ads on real device(even ads are loading on real device with debug and profile mode)

Answer (score 0):

Example for android native app.

Please test the production admobid , admod unit with the admob sample at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/admob/BannerExample
Replace existing admob ids and admob units, please check it the ads are getting served .

If no , then there might be some issue with you admob unit , or its not been fully approved for ads.

If you have created admob unit , recently , please wait for some time .

Hope that helps.